# how to host a website using xampp server?

Tags: php, html

I have created a website for sending emails, it works fine in localhost and in LAN connection, but I'm not able to open my website from another network.

I use my public IP address (found on whatsmyip.org), I have also forwarded port (80) to the server computer in my router settings page.

I'm using xampp version 5.6.3. please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your ISP is probably blocking out port 80

Comment: Or your router has the proper forwarding, but your modem doesn't...

Comment: is there any alternative for this?

Comment: U can change the port to a public port (>1024) by doing this people need to surf to yourpublicip:PORT

Comment: Your public IP address may change!

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS also

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your firewall allows incoming connections from port 80. To do this, open your computers firewall-configuration and create an incoming-rule for port 80. If you are using Windows 8 please refer to [this Microsoft-help-page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-firewall-from-start-to-finish).

To view your website from the internet, these conditions must be met:

- Make sure you use the correct ip
- Have an ISP that allows trafic on port 80 (thanks to DarkBee)
- Forward the port to the correct computer, using the nat of your router
- Configure your firewall to accept connections from port 80
- Make sure your xampp listens to all ip-adresses (see "Listen 80" in httpd.conf)